# How to throw an error in the LESS compiler

Tags: css, compiler-errors, less, throw, less-mixins

### Question

Is there any way to (programmatically) throw an error in the LESS compiler?

### Why?

I have been fiddling around with mixin guards today, because I wanted to generate my CSS margin based upon element size and element count.
I thought it would be cool to directly throw an error on compilation, when the elements won't fit in the wrapper.

**Info**: I am using the `lessc` compiler to compile my LESS code to CSS. I am not using any Javascript library to compile it on execution time.

### LESS source

```
// Variables
@wrapper-small:  830px;
@wrapper-big:   1200px;

.col-fixed(@size, @count, @wrapper)  when ((@size*@count) <= @wrapper)
{
    width: unit(@size, px);
    margin-right: unit( (@wrapper - @count * @size) / (@count - 1), px);    
}

.test_col_fixed {
    // will fail the mixin guard and output no generated CSS        
    .col-fixed(340, 3, @wrapper-small);

    // would work if not in comment
    // .col-fixed(340, 3, @wrapper-big);
}
```

### Generated CSS (small wrapper)

No output, because the code will not be generated due to the not matching mixin guard `when ((@size*@count) <= @wrapper) // 3*340 <= 830 is false`.

### Generated CSS (with working solution, big wrapper)

```
.test_col_fixed {
    width: 340px;
    margin-right: 90px;
}
```

Comment: Guards don't give any errors. The compiler just silently skips them when condition is matched. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30556401/restrict-mixin-values/30556891#30556891) is a related thread but I don't think you could apply pattern matching for your case. The best would be to follow the last snippet in my answer (which is to check for a not condition and introduce an error deliberately). Or you could print a custom message and check for it in compiled CSS.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but the valid values and extract function won't help in this case.

Comment: I wasn't referring to the valid values or extract snippets :) Please have a look at the final one with a deliberate error (`output: @bwahaha` part). That in my opinion is the only way you can make Less compiler fail when no guard is matched.

Comment: Oh, my bad. That works now. You could post that as an answer.

Comment: Ah, it would feel like I am duplicating my answer for rep :( If you like it, I wouldn't mind an upvote there :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Suggested, but strictly not recommended [solution by Harry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30556401/restrict-mixin-values/30556891#30556891)

```
.col-fixed(@size, @count, @wrapper) {
    & when ((@size*@count) <= @wrapper) {
        width: unit(@size, px);
        margin-right: unit( (@wrapper - @count * @size) / (@count - 1), px);  
    }
    & when ((@size*@count) > @wrapper) {
        /* there is no such variable and hence when the input value is not valid,
        compiler will complain that variable is undefined */
        output: @bwahahaha;
    }
}
```

Comment: Good, I was about to suggest moving the solution from question to a self answer and thanks :)